# Como buscar as últimas 5 imagens inseridas no banco e mostrar num carrossel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Pretendo pegar as últimas 5 imagens no banco e mostra-las num carrossel, com o respectivo título, e aquelas marcas que indicam a imagem que está sendo visualizada.
Estou trabalhando com Laravel 5.1 e mySql. 
Para mais esclarecimento, aqui vão algumas dicas:

**Para buscar os 5 registos (getNoticia)**

**Controller.php**

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

protected function getLemas() {
    return Lema::where('status_lm', 'Activo')->get();
}

protected function getIgreja() {
    return Igreja::All();
}

protected function getNoticia() {
    return Noticia::all()->take(5);
}
```

}

**NoticiaController.php**

```
class NoticiaController extends Controller
{

 // Display a listing of the resource.

 // @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('noticias.create-noticia')->with('lema', $this->getLemas())->with('igreja',$this->getIgreja());
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('imagem'))
    {
        $imagem = $request->file('imagem');
        $extensao = $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension();

        if($extensao != 'jpg' && $extensao != 'jpeg' && $extensao != 'png')
        {
            return back()->with('erro','Erro: Este arquivo não é uma imagem JPG ou PNG');
        }
    }

    $noticia = new Noticia();
    $noticia->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $noticia->conteudo = $request->conteudo;

    $noticia->imagem = "";
    $noticia->save();

    if(Input::file('imagem'))
    {
        File::move($imagem,public_path().'/imagem-noticia/noticia-id_'.$noticia->id.'.'.$extensao);
        $noticia->imagem = '/imagem-noticia/noticia-id_'.$noticia->id.'.'.$extensao;
        $noticia->save();
    }

    return redirect('/');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

Só para salientar que no NoticiaController.php, não implementei nada para essa mesma busca, por não saber como fazer. já procurei tanto, mas não encontrei matéria que possa me ajudar.

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
public function index()
{

    return view('home')
            ->with('lema', $this->getLemas())
            ->with('igreja',$this->getIgreja())
            ->with('noticia',$this->getNoticia());

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

**View Home.blade.php**

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-home" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="/imagem-noticia/noticia-id_11.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(4,162,183,0.9)">
                    <p><h3>Preparativos para o 2º Aniversário da Igreja</h3></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/imagem-noticia/noticia-id_12.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(4,162,183,0.9)">
                    <p><h3>Coral das moças estará na Igreja Baptista da Paz</h3></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/imagem-noticia/noticia-id_13.jpg" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(4,162,183,0.9)">
                    <p><h3>EBF - Inscrições Abertas</h3></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Nesta view, não meti o carrossel a pegar os dados dinamicamente no banco, mas sim a pegar as imagens a partir de uma pasta, como mostra a imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando na verdade, o meu propósito é carregar os dados de forma dinâmica e apresenta-los no carrossel (slides).

**A página fica assim**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fez o model? você tem o nome da tabela se não fez o model? e você fez o código em qual controller pode disponibilizar?

Comment: Acabei de editar agora mesmo @VirgilioNovic

Comment: `return Noticia::all()->take(5);` seria nessa linha ?

Comment: Não percebi. Seria quê?

Comment: então você quer retornar os últimos registro do model Noticia? e é nessa linha ???

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Como seria?

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar os últimos registro de uma tabela com [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) temos que ter uma ordenação, acredito que pelo `id` do registro auto incremento já resolva, outra ressalvar é que utilizou a técnica errada, porque, trouxe a massa de dados da sua tabela, depois pegou só o que precisa com a classe `Collection`, isso é um erro no desenvolvimento, então:

```
return Noticia::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
```

Na sua `View`:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-home" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @for($i=0;$i<$noticia->count();$i++)
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{$i}}"></li>
        @endfor
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @foreach(@noticia as $item)
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="{{$item->image}}" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(4,162,183,0.9)">
                <p><h3>Preparativos para o 2º Aniversário da Igreja</h3></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok @Virgilio! Agora, como passo isso no HomeController e depois na view, para passar em slides no carrossel?

Comment: @DanieldosSantos SE NÃO TEM A TELA ???

Comment: Não percebi @Virgilio. Quê tela?

Comment: Quem não está entendendo sou eu, se pergunta uma coisa depois pergunta outra coisa e ai no seu `controller` já tem o código e você me perguntou como passo isso para `view`, se seu código já está fazendo isso !!! @DanieldosSantos eu não entendi mais nada!

Comment: se reparares bem, no código da view não está definido para pegar os dados dinamicamente, mas sim, eu inseri o caminho das imagens, assim como o título. E a minha questão é: Como faço para mandar para o carrossel essas imagens com os seus respectivos títulos vindas do banco?

Comment: @DanieldosSantos fiz a edição da `view`

Comment: fiz do jeito que mandaste, deu erro. Mas só mudei a forma de inserir o "for" e o "foreach", usando " <?php foreach($noticia as $item): ?>" e resultou, mas as imagens estão intactas, não se movimentam, os controls e os indicadores não aparecem,  e as 3 imagens surgiram em simultaneo, como na imagem que vou carregar agora.

Comment: @DanieldosSantos o seu problema é maior e muito ampla, e do jeito que fiz era pra funcionar, talvez a sua `view` não esteja com `blade.php` por isso ... bom é muito ampla